# Horizontal jQuery sliding slides down instead

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slider

I want to have a horizontal slider to slide through "pages" on a single view (in Wordpress).
My code is almost working, but instead of sliding the block horizontally, it slides the page down a little instead (asif pressing the down button on the keyboard).

Here is my code:

```
    <style>
    #main
    {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #primary 
    {
        position: relative; 
    }

    div.content div 
    {
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
        top:25px;
        left:0px;
    }
    #box1 { background: yellow; left:0px;}
    #box2 { background: orange; left:100%; }
    #box3 { background: #838EDE; left:200%; }
    #box4 { background: #FFFCC; left:300%; }
    #box5 { background: red; left:400%; }

    #navlinks li 
    {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #F3F3F3;
        border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E4;
        height: 20px;
        width: 15%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e4;
        margin: 0px 5px;
    }

    #navlinks > li.current, #navlinks > li:hover
    {
        background: #cc0000;
        border-color: #A00;
    }

    #navlinks > li a 
    {
        color: #303030;
        text-decoration: none; 
    }

    #navlinks > li.current a, #navlinks > li:hover a 
    {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #navlinks > li.tab1, #navlinks > li.tab5
    {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #navlinks > li:after
    {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 50px 0 50px 50px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f3f3f3;
        line-height: 0px;
    }
</style>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <ul id="navlinks">
        <li class="tab tab1 current" data-href="#box1"><a>Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab tab2" data-href="#box2"><a>Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab tab3" data-href="#box3"><a>Link 3</a></li>
        <li class="tab tab4" data-href="#box4"><a>Link 4</a></li>
        <li class="tab tab5" data-href="#box5"><a>Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content" role="main">
        <div id="box1">Blok 1</div>
        <div id="box2">Blok 2</div>
        <div id="box3">Blok 3</div>
        <div id="box4">Blok 4</div>
        <div id="box5">Blok 5</div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(j) {
    j(document).on('click', '#navlinks li', function() {
        j('.tab').removeClass('current');
        j(this).addClass('current');

        var panel = j(this).data('href');
        j.scrollTo(panel, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Any unknown classes or id's you might see in the `<style></style>` tags are from the header or footer (such as `#main`).
The `scrollTo()` function is from a [plugin](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

I tried to create a jsFiddle but that came out even worse :/.
Does anyone see anyhting wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** 
I have made a jsFiddle with my current setting: 
[jsfiddle.net/UkP4X](http://jsfiddle.net/UkP4X)

Comment: Horizontal means ,Each box should have 100% width or Within 100% width,all these box(id) will have each 20%;

Comment: @KesaVan So I should set the width of all boxes to 100%?

Comment: ok,I will update you soon..

Comment: @user1433479 i can't find any documentation on `scrollTo()` function in query, other than this [Plugin](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: @TilwinJoy Yup, I got the plugin set. It's not telling me anything like "scrollTo is not a function" and it does in fact scroll. Problem is that it scrolls me down the page instead of horizontally through the blocks.

Comment: @user1433479 Then you should mention in your question that you're using a plugin and mention it's detail.. otherwise people will think that's you're simply trying to do it in jQuery.. anyway i'm working on something else to help you achieve this without a plugin.. ;)

Comment: @user1433479: http://jsfiddle.net/7Q3CB/ ,Now what function is not working for you?

Comment: All funtions were working. The fiddle doesn't because it's missing the jQuery plugin for scrollTo.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using a plugin, using css3 `transition`.

add the following css:

```
.content{
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 clear:both;
}
.content div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
 transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
.show{
 transform:translate(0%);
}
.hide{
 transform:translate(100%);
}
```

In your HTML, add `show` class for the first tab you want to show and apply `hide` class for the rest.

Then change your script to

```
$(document).ready(function (j) {
  $(document).on('click', '#navlinks a', function () {
    var panel = $(this).data('href');
    $('.show').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('show');
    $(panel).toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/xmahz/)

**UPDATE**

As per comments, for old browser compatibility, you can combine css and use jQuery `animate()` an follows:

css:

```
content{
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 clear:both;
}
.content div {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 left:100%;
}
div.shown{
 left:0%;
}
```

in HTML, add the class `shown` for the div which should be initially visible.

script:

```
$(document).ready(function (j) {
  $(document).on('click', '#navlinks a', function () {
    var panel = $(this).data('href');
    $('.shown').removeClass('shown').css('left','100%');
    $(panel).animate({
        left: '0%'
    },500, function(){
     $(panel).addClass('shown');
    });
  });
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/mb39t/)

Comment: There's one issue I forgot to mention: it has to work for IE6 and higher ;_;. Is there a way I can achieve this without CSS3?

Comment: I've put this in, and I can see it change the `left` property from 100% to 0% in the html code, but the elements are invisible to me (but not hidden/greyed out in html). I'll update my code with what I have so far.

Comment: I've changed my code. The class "shown" and the left property are being applied perfectly so I don't think the issue is with the jQuery right now.

Comment: @user1433479 please don't update code in the question according to answers, it'll confuse the future readers. If you want to share what you've after doing something, create a jsfiddle and share the link to it, mentioning that it's an update..

Comment: I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UkP4X/. But in the fiddle I can see the blocks, which is not the case in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not an answer to your problem I can recommend to use https://github.com/thebird/Swipe for Sliders. It's very forgiving and works on mobile devices.

To better see your problem I's suggest you format the CSS not in a row for better readability and using classes instead of ID's for styling.

```
a { 
  margin-right:15px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:blue;
}
```